# Bash regex with hyphen and dot

Tags: regex, bash, shell

I'm trying to match hostname with regex.
For some reason the following code fails.

```
#!/bin/bash 
CONFIGURATION=m1si-ngxi-ddb01

#check configuration format
TMP_CONFIGURATION=",${CONFIGURATION}"
re=',[a-zA-Z0-9\-_\.]+'
if ! [[ $TMP_CONFIGURATION =~ $re ]]
then
        echo "configuration parttern mismatch."
        exit 1
fi
```

Testing:

```
[oracle@m1s-nyyy-db01 nir]$ vi a.sh
[oracle@m1s-nyyy-db01 nir]$
```

Comment: Use `re=',[a-zA-Z0-9_.-]+'`

Comment: Notice that you can replace `[a-zA-Z0-9]` with `[[:alnum:]]`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The pattern you have is failing due to "escaped" chars and the fact that `-` is not at the end/start of the bracket expression. The `\` is always treated as a literal backslash inside bracket expressions, they do not form any escape sequences. The hyphen is tricky, see the [9.3.5 RE Bracket Expression](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap09.html), Point 7:

> The `<hyphen-minus>` character shall be treated as itself if it occurs first (after an initial '^', if any) or last in the list, or as an ending range point in a range expression.

Use

```
CONFIGURATION=m1si-ngxi-ddb01
#check configuration format
TMP_CONFIGURATION=",$CONFIGURATION"
re=',[a-zA-Z0-9_.-]+'
if ! [[ $TMP_CONFIGURATION =~ $re ]]
then
        echo "configuration parttern mismatch."
        exit 1
fi
```

See the [online demo](https://ideone.com/T7HeSi). Note that there is no need to put `CONFIGURATION` inside curly braces, `$CONFIGURATION` = `${CONFIGURATION}`.

Comment: wouldn't `,[a-zA-Z0-9_\-]+` also match `,m1si-ngxi-ddb01`?

Comment: @User123 It will match `,m1si-ngxi-ddb01`, but it [will also match](https://ideone.com/CkneE5) `,\m1si-ngxi-ddb01`