# Bash: Regex to determine if string contains at least one of @, #, $, %, &, *, +, -, =

Tags: bash

I need to check if a string contains at least one of characters: @, #, $, %, &, *, +, -, =
Everything works well until I put asterisk to regex pattern, even escaping the asterisk. Here is my code, please help, thx!

```
if [[ ! "$1" =~ .*[@#%$\&+=-\*].* ]]; then
  echo "Password must contain at least 1 special character(s)."
  exit 1
fi
```

Comment: Move the `-` to the beginning of the list, ie. use `[-@#%$\&+=*]`,

Comment: It's working. Thx James. Could you explain why that happen?

Comment: The dash within the [...] is for a range like [A-Z], unless it's at the start [- ...] or end [ ... -], like you probably had before the * got added.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55377810/bash-regex-with-hyphen-and-dot

Comment: Why using a regexp here, when simple wildcard matching would be sufficient? I.e. `if [[ $1 == *[-@#%$\&+=*]* ]]; then ....`

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using multiple escapes? Sometimes the reason the single backslash doesn't work is because there are several "levels" of interpretation going on. So two, three or four escapes might work where one doesn't. Here's one extra backslash, if this doesn't work, you can try adding in more.

```
if [[ ! "$1" =~ .*[@#%$\&+=-\\*].* ]]; then
  echo "Password must contain at least 1 special character(s)."
  exit 1
fi
```

Comment: No, multiple escapes not working. But putting the - to the beginning works.

Comment: Ah yes, I missed that there, sorry. Hyphen = range. Can be useful at times, but definitely needs to be on the "checklist" when things go wrong!